# Repeating time (1 AM-1:59:59 AM) on first Sunday of November - Daylight Savings ending day - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, dst, zone

Good afternoon.

I understand that there is "each second of each minute of one specific hour" is repeated (1 AM - 1:59:59 AM) on first Sunday of November (Closing day of Daylight Saving time). So, duration from 0:00 AM (midnight) to 3 AM is 4 hours on that day.

> SELECT   TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2021-11-07 03:00:00 US/Mountain',
> 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss TZR')
> - TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2021-11-07 00:00:00 US/Mountain', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss TZR') FROM DUAL;

> The above query is returning 4 hours as expected.

Here is my question -
I want to basically differentiate/represent the two occurrences of 1 AM (or any time between 1 AM, and 1:59:59 AM). How can I do? (I am using Oracle 12.1)

BTW, this following query is resulting 1 hour 30 minutes, so '2021-11-07 01:30:00 MST' represents the second instance of 1:30 AM. In the same manner, I was expecting '2021-11-07 01:30:00 MDT' to be the first instance, however it is resulting ORA-01882: timezone region not found. BTW, I prefer to have US/Mountain (or something like that) for region, rather MST vs. MDT

> SELECT   TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2021-11-07 03:00:00 MST', 'yyyy-mm-dd
> hh24:mi:ss TZR')
> - TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2021-11-07 01:30:00 MST', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss TZR') FROM DUAL;

Sorry if I confused you. Please let me know if any questions.
Any help?

Thank you

Viswa

---

Added later:
I think I found the answer: We need to use TZD flag, and use MST/MDT values.
I did not like that as I prefer to use the region (such as US/Mountain).
So any enhancements will be appreciated.

> SELECT   TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2021-11-07 03:00:00 US/Mountain',
> 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss TZR')
> - TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2021-11-07 00:00:00 US/Mountain', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss TZR') FROM DUAL;

-- 4 hours:00 minutes, as expected

> SELECT   TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2021-11-07 03:00:00 MST', 'yyyy-mm-dd
> hh24:mi:ss TZD')
> - TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2021-11-07 01:30:00 MDT', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss TZD') FROM DUAL;

-- 2:30 minutes
-- So any values ranging from 1:00 to 1:59:59 with a time zone of MDT are the first instance values.

> SELECT   TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2021-11-07 03:00:00 MST', 'yyyy-mm-dd
> hh24:mi:ss TZD')
> - TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2021-11-07 01:30:00 MST', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss TZD') FROM DUAL;

-- 1 hour:30 minutes
-- So any values ranging from 1:00 to 1:59:59 with a time zone of MST are the second instance values.

Comment: You can try SYS_EXTRACT_UTC to convert it into UTC Time

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I just want to keep it simple, and when I pass MDT, MST values along with TZD flag, that seems working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Value `TIMESTAMP '2021-11-07 01:00:00 US/Mountain'` is ambiguous, it could be
`2021-11-07 01:00:00-06:00` or `2021-11-07 01:00:00-07:00`

If you don't specify the daylight-saving-time status then Oracle defaults to the standard time, (MST in your case)

You need to provide both, the timezone region and the Daylight Saving Time information, i.e. `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2021-11-07 01:00:00 US/Mountain MST', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss TZR TZD')` or `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2021-11-07 01:00:00 US/Mountain MDT', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss TZR TZD')`

Note, if you alter your session with `ALTER SESSION SET ERROR_ON_OVERLAP_TIME = TRUE;` then for ambiguous times like `TIMESTAMP '2021-11-07 01:00:00 US/Mountain'` Oracle does not default to standard time but raise an error:

> ORA-01883: overlap was disabled during a region transition

Don't mistake "Time zone region" (`TRZ`) with "Daylight saving information" (`TZD`), however `MST` can mean both:

```
SELECT *
FROM V$TIMEZONE_NAMES
WHERE TZABBREV in ('MST', 'MDT');
```

Calculations of `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` values are internally always performed on UTC times.

See [Support for Daylight Saving Time](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch4datetime.htm#NLSPG266)

Comment: I understand and agree with providing both US/Mountain (TZR) and MST/MDT (TZD) to eliminate the confusion. I also like having ERROR_ON_OVERLAP_TIME setting to TRUE, just to avoid default value of MST.